# Is this formula just the same like purity formula validation?

Tags: validation, cluster-analysis

Most paper that i have read use an external validation for clustering accuracy with this formula :
       [image: r accuracy]
where ai is the number of data objects occurring both in ith cluster
and its corresponding true class, and n is the number of data objects in the data set. According to this measure, a higher value of r indicates
a better clustering result, with perfect clustering yielding a value
of r = 1.0

Is this formula same like purity formula or something else?
You can read purity here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95731/how-to-calculate-purity

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the claim of the paper that this would be "commonly" used. The common measures are ARI (Adjusted Rand Index) and NMI (Normalized Mutual Information).

But yes, tonne this looks the same as purity. With the same flaws.

The measure they used supposedly is biased against breaking "true" clusters into smaller chunks. If k=n, every point is its own cluster, then all so will be 1, and this measure will evaluate the result as perfect.

So you must not use it to compare results with different k.